# )Two-spring mass system

Tags: proof-verification, mathematical-modeling

Consider two-spring mass system below.

|--/////--|M|---////--|

Let the left spring be spring 1 with elasticity coefficient $k_1$ and unstretched length $l_1$. Also, the right spring is spring 2 with elasticity coefficient $k_2$ and unstretched length $l_2$. The |M| stands for mass $m$ and the "|--" and "--|" is the wall that system is attached to. I was asked to come up with a model for this.

Here's what I think. Let $p$ be the distance from wall to wall.
Let's apply force to the positive $x$-direction, so mass $m$ moves to positive $x$-direction. Also, let $x$ be the distance from left wall to the mass. When mass $m$ moves the positive $x$-direction, we have spring force of spring 1 to the negative $x$-direction. Spring 1 stretched by $x-l_1$. So the spring force is $-k_1(x-l_1)$. Also, when mass $m$ moves to positive $x$-direction, we have another spring force. Spring 2 is compressed by $(l_2-(p-x))$, so the force is $-k_2(l_2-(p-x))$ since the force is to the negative $x$ direction.

Using newton's law, we have $F=ma$, so the model for the system is 
$$-k_1(x-l_1)-k_2(l_2-(p-x)) = m \frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}$$

Is this model right? Also, in the book, I was given that the distance from wall to wall is $p$. I was asked to explain why it is not necessary for $p=l_1 + l_2$. I am not sure why it is not.

Comment: You need $k_1$ and $k_2$ in your formula.  As for the question about $p$, fix $p$ and take two springs from the shelf.  Why should $p$ equal $l_1+l_2$?  Can you assemble the system even if it does not?

Comment: what do you mean by "unstretched length", the spring at t=0 are stretched or not?

Comment: Your model does not apply newton's law correctly: one of your springs does not push/pull the mass when it should (try with moving the mass in the direction of "x". the sign of the forces will not make sense).  The reason for which the distance from the wall is not necessary depends on your derivation of the system. So a guiding question will be: why is it that the distance between the mass and the wall is not an issue for each of the forces (inertial and spring related)? This is something that I think is worth answering yourself.

Comment: @gimusi at $t=0$, we have unstretched length. So unstretched length = the original spring's length we started with.

Comment: @Snifkes I am not sure what force is missing. If the mass moves to the right, then didn't we only have two forces. That is, spring 1 force and spring 2 force, both of them to the left.

Comment: @ardhemist At the previous edit, the force was given as: -k1(x-l1)+k2(x-l2). How to note that this is wrong: assume both springs are of equal stiffness (k_i) with equal nonstretched length (l_i), it will result in the mass not affected by any of the springs. which is wrong.

Comment: @ardhemist Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation should have subscripts on the $k$s because in the problem the spring constants can be different.  The $l_2-x$ term is not correct because you are measuring $x$ from the left wall.  The force is proportional to the difference between $l_2$ and the distance from the mass to the right wall.  That distance is $p-x$ so your $l_2-x$ should be $l_2-(p-x)$.  You don't need the sum of the distances between the walls to be $l_1+l_2$.  If it is different, at equilibrium the two springs will each be stretched in such a way that they apply equal and opposite forces to the mass.  The mass will then oscillate around the equilibrium position.  It simplifies things a bit if you measure $x$ from equilibrium, instead of from the left spring equilibrium.

Comment: I have edited the equation. Is it right, now? Also, can you elaborate a bit what you mean by "x from equilibrium"?. Do you mean I should measure the displacement of mass respect to the mass' original position? Like this. Let $y$ be the distance of movement of mass $m$. When the mass moves $y$ distance away from its original position, we have spring force of spring 1 to negative $x$-direction, that is, $-ky$.

Comment: I meant you should choose the origin of $x$ to be the position where there is no net force from the springs.  It is not important, but some of the terms of the equation drop out that way.  You just get a mass of $m$ oscillating with an effective single spring of constant $k_1+k_2$.  The updated equation looks right, but I just glanced at it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the system at rest with the spring at the unstretched length; this configuration corresponds to the position x=0 for the mass (1 DOF).

Now consider the system in a configuration at $x\neq 0$ then

$$F=ma\implies -k_1x-k_2x = m \frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}$$